# u-boot spi initialisation in omap3

Tags: spi, u-boot, omap

I was looking into spi driver in u boot , here is a small snippet from

[omap_spi.c](https://gitorious.org/beagleboard-validation/u-boot/source/cfd0236321db1b2d18d0e03926cdbed4ea2816b5:drivers/spi/omap_spi.c)

```
void spi_init(void)
{
gpMCSPIRegs = (MCSPI_REGS *)MCSPI_SPI1_IO_BASE;

unsigned long u, n;

/* initialize the multipad and interface clock */
spi_init_spi1();

/* soft reset */
CSP_BITFINS(gpMCSPIRegs->SYSCONFIG, SPI_SYSCONFIG_SOFTRESET, 1);
for (n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
    u = CSP_BITFEXT(gpMCSPIRegs->SYSSTATUS,
            SPI_SYSSTATUS_RESETDONE);
    if (u)
        break;
}

  ...more code
}
```

here in 
[omap_spi.h](https://gitorious.org/beagleboard-validation/u-boot/source/cfd0236321db1b2d18d0e03926cdbed4ea2816b5:drivers/spi/omap_spi.h)

```
  #define CSP_BITFINS(var, bit, val) \
      (CSP_BITFCLR(var, bit)); (var |= CSP_BITFVAL(bit, val))
```

my confusion here is that when they do soft reset , they call this CSP_BITFINS macro. inside this macro all they do is just manipulate bits and fill structures. where do they access that hardware registers to configure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look further, you'll find that the pointer they are using, gpMCSPIRregs, is volatile and pointing at the memory-mapper hardware registers. The bits they are setting/clearing are in the hardware registers.